# Referenced Integer object not incremented

Tags: java

I'm developing an java application and now I noted an a strange behaviour that confused me. I have the following situation:

```
    Integer currentIndex = 0;
    doSomethings(currentIndex);
    System.out.println("Print "+currentIndex);


    private void doSomethings(Integer currentIndex){
        //Do other things and update my current index
        currentIndex++;


    }
```

but I get always 0 like value. I remember that the objects are passed like reference in java, while the primitive types like copy. Why Do I get 0 in this case?

Comment: If possible, avoid using these boxed classes in java. If you do operations like this, there is implicit unboxing in the background, and in case you would return it, there would be a re-boxing.

Comment: Your method `doSomething` doesn't return anything, and you're confusing yourself having a variable called `currentIndex` which is also the name of the passed-in variable. As it stands your method simply increments the (local) passed-in value, which isn't the same as the one you declare in the main call code.

Comment: Note that reference in Java and C are two different things. Reference in Java is somewhat like pointer in C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instance of `Integer` is **immutable**. It means you cannot change its value. When you increase it by one, `Integer` gets converted into `int` (this is called ["unboxing"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)), then this `int` gets increased by one. You can even cast it back to `Integer`. But this will be already *another* instance of `Integer`, not the one you've passed to the method. That's why your original reference stays equal to zero all the time.

Byte code :

```
private static void doSomethings(java.lang.Integer);
  Code:
   Stack=2, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokevirtual   #56; //Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I  --> get the int value of the Integer
   4:   iconst_1 --> constant value 1
   5:   iadd   --> add int value and 1
   6:   invokestatic    #16; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/In --> get another integer with value increased by 1
teger;
   9:   astore_0
   10:  return
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting construct.

Note that Objects in Java don't allow custom operator implementations. And that the ++ operator is not defined for a java Object.

So java will do a trick that is call 'auto boxing'. This converts `Integer` to `int` and vice versa when needed.

What happens when you do:

```
Interger myInt = 0;
int i = myInt++; // this line
```

is as follows:
`myInt` will be converted to `int`, then that int value is incremented and store in `i`. Note that the integer value is not saved to `myInt`.

This is what happens in your function, the `++` only happens in a temporary variable, not in the actual `Integer` object. Note that because the `Integer` object is immutable, this is not even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone gives correct solution and **beworker** also give nice reason. I add up one reason.

Java always pass everything by value. So in your code when you pass currentIndex it pass by value so any changes to `currentIndex` in `dosomething()` method not reflected outside of block.

For more [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) . I refer you to see Eng.Fouad answer he very well explained this concept
.

Answer (score 1):

Java is not pass by reference. It is pass by value ( value of a reference). Above code does not work since `Integer` is an Immutable class. So you cannot change it's value.

So get your method work you need to return value in your method as below.

```
private Integer doSomethings(Integer currentIndex){

            return currentIndex++;   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    currentIndex = doSomethings(currentIndex);
    private Integer doSomethings(Integer currentIndex){
          //Do other things and update my current index
          return currentIndex++;     
    }
```

Comment: Is it same as `++currentIndex`?

Comment: also the method should be called as : currentIndex = doSomethings(currentIndex);

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following code

```
  Integer currentIndex = 0;
  currentIndex = doSomethings(currentIndex);
  System.out.println("Print "+currentIndex);


  private Integer doSomethings(Integer currentIndex,){
    //Do other things and update my current index
    return currentIndex++;
```

doSomethings() is increment the value of the currentIndex and return that. Then store that object into the currentIndex reference

Good Luck !!!

Answer (score 0):

Java is pass by value these two articles explain well

http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryCups.jsp
http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp

Read in that order.